Solution to Photoshop AI
I hope the question fits the category.
We use Adobe Photoshop with the new generic fill feature. But we encounter the following problem:
We are configured so that the images we are looking for will go through a proxy server that filters the images [we have no way to disable this].
The problem we encounter is that many times the images are not enough to return from the budget test to the software to wait.
Is there a way to extend the waiting time for the image to be returned in the software?
We note that if the same request is asked again, it is not a solution because the new image is sent again for review, and again it is not enough to return.
Any solution will be gladly accepted.
Thanks in advance
